# Как сделать локализацию приложения имеющего очень много модулей?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, локализация

Есть WinForms приложение с довольно большой библиотекой dll файлов (пара десятков), которые в свою очередь содержат как UI контролы, как и много текстовых выражений. Все это необходимо локализировать.

С локализированием мало работал и если что и нашел в Сети, то только на уровне одного ехе-шника. Поэтому попрошу совета у Общества как реализовать сие. Сделать централизировано или для каждой длл-ки своя система переводов?

Comment: Начать нужно с [глобализации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/eaa7b9c0.aspx) ([eng](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/globalizing-windows-forms)) - подготовки приложения к последующей локализации. Нужно учитывать, в частности, что текст на разных языках имеет разную длину, поэтому может не влезать в жестко заданные размеры контролов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея проста: 
1) у тебя есть файлы, ответственные за перевод, в них массив с данными, примерно такой:

```
[
 'word'   => 'слово',
 'train'  => 'поезд'
]
```

2) Подключаешь файл в конфигах приложения
3) Делаешь логику, как достучатся к значению ключа с массива 
4) Ставишь метки там, где это нужно
5) При формировании ответа заменяешь свои метки на значения из массива

P.S. Сам пишу на PHP, поэтому сорри, кода С предоставить не могу, надеюсь суть идеи была ясна

Comment: Спасибо, по сути так и сделаю, но в контексте локальных ресурсов.